# How to get azure pipeline pending status with cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I have an azure pipeline, which requires manual approval to proceed at the final stage, and I'd like to do something like

1. fetch pipeline status
2. when status is something like "waiting" or "pending", approve with api

I have tried some commands like the following ones to fetch pipeline status:
`az pipelines build list --organization <org> --project <project>`
`az pipelines runs show --id <run id> --organization <org> --project <project>`
but for the output they all with **"status": "inProgress"** instead of **the expected "pending/waiting"**

the question will be are there any other ways that I can tell whether pipeline is pending for approval through status or other cli output, or any suggestions?

Comment: May I know if below answer helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't find the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest) commands to retrieve the pending status. However, we can get the pending status by calling the [Approvals - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) REST API.

[image]

Then call the [Approvals - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) REST API to approve the pending.

[image]

We can call the REST APIs in a script, just get all pending approvals first, then approve them in a loop. The following PowerShell script for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$orgnurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}",
   [string]$projectName = "0424Test",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))


#Get all the pending approvals

$approvalsurl = "$orgnurl/$projectName/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$approvals = ((Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approvalsurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value | Where {$_.status -eq 'pending'}).id

cls
write-host "Pending approvals:"$approvals


#Approve the pendings in a loop

foreach ($approvalId in $approvals){


function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"   
    [
      {
        "approvalId": "$approvalId",
        "comment": "Approving",
        "status": "approved"
      }
    ]  
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$approveurl = "$orgnurl/$projectName/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1" 
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approveurl -Method PATCH -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
Write-Host ($result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20)
}
```

Screenshots for your reference:

Pending approval:
[image]

Approved:
[image]

Comment: sry for forgot to accept the answer, since later on decided to do approval right after pipeline's creation based on pipeline id, this way there is no need to check the pending status.
But I believe this answer will work as expected, and if using 'az devops invoke' properly this can work with az cli also, big thanks!